# Put UI strings into resources

Tags: c#, uwp

I followed the instructions in *Put strings into resource files, instead of putting them directly in code or markup* in [Put UI strings into resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources) (except I don't understand step 4f). The structure in the Solution Explorer of the resources in my project is:

[image]

That is the hierarchy for the project's shared node. I opened the Resources1.resw file and added a couple of strings.

Then *Add string resource identifiers to code and markup* in that article has the following:

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
```

When I have that I get:

```
WinRT information: ResourceMap Not Found.
```

I have tried many other possibilities that I have found from searching but either I get that error or the class or method (in other solutions) do not exist for my project. I assume there is something relevant missing from that article.

Using C#, how do I get strings from that resources file ?

Comment: try var loader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentThread();

Comment: Does it work if you change the name of `Resources1.resw` to `Resources.resw`?

Comment: Sorry, @Dave Smits, but I get *'ResourceLoader' does not contain a definition for 'GetForCurrentThread'* for GetForCurr‌​entThread. I get that for other methods that other solutions suggest.

Comment: Yes, @Romasz, that works.

Comment: You dont need to rename your file. See my answer

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to rename your resource file. If the name of the resource file isnt the default (`Resources.resw`), you can add the special name in the `GetForCurrentView` method. 
In your case the call should be:

```
var loader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources1.resw");
```

Source:[GetForCurrentView(System.String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader#Windows_ApplicationModel_Resources_ResourceLoader_GetForCurrentView_System_String_)

Comment: It is a matter of personal preference and I prefer to use the default.

Comment: My question is about the article. The article's instructions work except for the name Resources1.resw. Therefore the best solution **for the article** (that I asked about) is to change the name of Resources1.resw. Microsoft writes introductory articles and it is frustrating when people try to expand the scope of the articles. Other articles are more extensive about internationalization and such and are more complicated..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to specify default language in app.xaml for your actual frame?

> ```
>         myFrame = new Frame
>         {
>             Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0]
>         };
> ```

Or more specific:

> Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages['en']